# Mimic Explorer.exe So I can Customize It's Toolbars

Tags: vba, explorer

I am trying to make a form of explorer.exe so I can customize the toolbars to do more things that I want, such as create a list of what is in the current directory I'm looking at.
I'm currently trying to put a pannel onto the windows form and am using the code:

```
panel1.display("C:\")
```

I've also tried:

```
panel1.url("C:\")
```

And:

```
panel1.navigate("C:\")
```

When I used Java in class I could construct something similar to this with panels, so can someone please tell my why I can't get the panel to display the contents of the C: drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are extremely close, on the right track. What you should do instead is use a simple web browser. It can do more than just browse internet pages. If you use the following code it should work:

```
webbrowser1.navigate("C:\")
```